# How do I remove a Facebook app notification from the app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I post an app-to-user notification as per the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#notifications), it does only have a 'Create' section in the docs, but I'm just wondering if there is any way I can then remove them, like you can with apprequests (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests)?

We're building a game which allows for random-user play, so need app-to-user communication, but don't want to use an app-to-user apprequest because they don't get notifications.  But with app-to-user notifications, they clutter up notification list if you're not able to delete them from the app.

I know in you can call https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications/, but you need the 'manage_notifications' extended permissions for that, which then gives you access to *all* your notifications, which we think is overkill and unnecessary.

Is there any other way?